# What is the percentage reduction of reload time when using Sleight of Hand?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

By how much does Sleight of Hand reduce reload time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to CoD wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Sleight_of_Hand)

> Sleight of Hand decreases the reload time for all weapons by 50%. Its
>   pro version decreases the time it takes to aim down sights on all
>   weapons excluding sniper rifles, to prevent quickscoping.

Comment: actually your comment about the pro version isn't true.  Slight of hand pro doesn't speed up ADS in Modern Warfare 3, it decreases the time it takes to switch weapons.  The slight of hand perk pro you're thinking of was in MW2.